# Background acompanhar imagem responsivo

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber como uma imagem em background poderia ficar alinhada com outra imagem que está sobre ela

Está imagem que e uma bola, gostaria que ela ficasse no fundo,
Quando a tela está em uma resolução menor, não fica ajustado, mais se você abre toda a tela ela se ajusta.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6  img-fundo">
        <img id="front1"  class="img-responsive" src="./imagens/produtostopo070417v2.png" usemap="#Map1">
           <map name="Map1">
             <area shape="rect" coords="1,47,146,400" href="#" target="_parent">
             <area shape="rect" coords="161,46,352,402" href="#" target="_parent">
             <area shape="rect" coords="371,48,551,407" href="#" target="_parent">
           </map>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 img-fundo">
        <img id="front2"  class="img-responsive " src="./imagens/produtostopo070417.png" usemap="#Map2">
          <map name="Map2">
             <area shape="rect" coords="-3,53,145,392" href="#" target="_parent">
             <area shape="rect" coords="174,41,346,397" href="#" target="_parent">
             <area shape="rect" coords="379,39,542,394" href="#" target="_parent">
          </map>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: amigo quando colocar caminho de imagens informe o caminho publico online por exemplo http://spotify.sisguardiao.com.br/layout/imagens/produtostopo070417v2.png

Comment: Não é possível ver nada porque as imagens não estão hospedadas em domínio público e sim apontando para as pastas no seu pc.